# How to integrate WinMerge with TortoiseSvn after installation?

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, winmerge

When you install winmerge after TortoiseSVN it gives you the option of associating winmerge with Tortoise. But if we install TortoiseSVN after winmerge how can we associate Winmerge to be used instead of Tortoise default diff viewer.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can open the TortoiseSVN settings and manually enter it:

[image]

My command line from the screenshot above is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -x -ub -dl %bname -dr %yname %base %mine

If you install TortoiseSVN after WinMerge, probably the easiest way would be to uninstall and re-install WinMerge again.

Comment: I like to see the changed version in the left pane, so this is mine: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -ub -dl %yname -dr %bname %mine %base`

Comment: I know the installer sets this options, but the [official documenation](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html), doesn't mention the `-ub` option. Looking at `MergeCmdLineInfo.cpp`, I found out that this means `-ul` and `-ur` combined. Source code says this option is deprecated and only `-u` works too.

Comment: I also added a `/wl` since I don't see why i would want/allow to edit the base here.  The [docs](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html) only use windows-style switched (`/` not `-`) so i went with that but i guess both work.

Answer (score 26):

You can also use WinMerge for merging changes.  In the settings window (as above) under Merge Tool, enter:

32-bit os

```
C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -x -ub -dl %tname -dr %yname %theirs %mine
```

64-bit os

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -x -ub -dl %tname -dr %yname %theirs %mine
```

Then you'll get the remote file in the left pane, your local (changed) file in the right pane.

Comment: Actually, I think it works better when you resolve it afterwards if you use the "wl" (read-only left pane) and %merged for output path. I use the following: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -x -ub -dl %tname -wl -dr %yname %theirs %mine %merged`

Answer (score 23):

**Diff Viewer**

```
C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -x -u -wl -dl %bname -dr %yname %base %mine
```

With:

- `-e` enables you to close WinMerge with a single <kbd>Esc</kbd> key press.
- `-x` closes WinMerge (after displaying an information dialog) when you start a comparison of identical files.
- `-u` prevents WinMerge from adding either path (left or right) to the Most Recently Used (MRU) list.
- `-wl` opens the left side as read-only.
- `-dl %bname` specifies a description of the original file in the left side title bar.
- `-dr %yname` specifies a description of your own file in the right side title bar.
- `%base` specifies the left side file with the original file.
- `%mine` specifies the right side file with your own file.

**Merge Tool**

```
C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -x -u -wl -dl %tname -dr %yname %theirs %mine %merged
```

With the same options as above except:

- `-dl %tname` specifies a description of the repository file in the left side title bar.
- `%theirs` specifies the left side file with the repository file.
- `%merged` specifies the conflicted file, the result of the merge operation.

Comment: For me, it only worked to click the Advanced button and Edit the .docx line, pasting the command line into the External Program field.

Comment: Thanks for useful summary of what each different command line switch does.

Comment: Thanks for calling out the Merge Tool setting!

Comment: Great answer. Except that Winmerge now comes in 64 bits flavor, so "x86" in the path is not requested anymore :)